# Needs help regarding print in asp.net (need to remove datetime from printpage)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, datetime, printing

i am using below code to print my content of webpage in asp.net using javascript

```
       window.print(document.getElementById('dvPrint'));
```

when i do print, it automatically adds date time on page.. (i think because of page setup) in firefox. please tell me how can i remove this setting. i mean i dont want datetime to be printed automatically on my print page (even if its set in pagesetup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think javascript cant do that you have to remove header and footer from your browser's page setup